# Searched MySQL Database, now I want to replace the Email field

Tags: php, mysql

I have already searched the mysql database with search.php with using my form in registration.php. Now I want to replace the user email with another email according to that persons ID. How would I do this.

Here is search.php
`

```
$searchTerm = ($_GET['keyname']);

//check whether the name parsed is empty
if($searchTerm == "")
{
    echo "Enter name you are searching for.";
    exit();
}



$host = "localhost";
$my_db = "xxx";
$my_user = "xxx";
$my_password = "xxx";
$link = mysqli_connect("localhost",$my_user,$my_password,$my_db);
$query = "SELECT * FROM yesData WHERE socialSecNum LIKE '%$searchTerm%' ";
$results = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if(mysqli_num_rows($results) >= 1)
{
    $output = "";
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($results))
    {
        $output .= "First Name: " . $row['nameFirst'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "Last Name: " . $row['nameLast'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "SSN: " . $row['socialSecNum'] . "<br />";
        $output .= "ID: " . $row['id'] . "<br /><br />";
        $output .= "Email: " . $row['addressEmail'] . "<br /><br />";
    }
    echo $output;
}
else
    echo "There was no matching record for the name " . $searchTerm;
?>
```

`

Here is registration.php

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html dir="ltr" lang="en-US" >
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8" />
<title>Registration Page</title>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Registration</h1>
<form action="search.php" method="get">
  <label>Name:
  <input type="text" name="keyname" />
  </label>
  <input type="submit" value="Search" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: same principle as the search. you have a form, and when the submit button is pressed you put the data into an UPDATE statement

Comment: You'd use an `UPDATE` query.

Answer (score 0):

Easy, use UPDATE in MySQL.

W3 Schools' syntax:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET column1=value, column2=value2,...
WHERE some_column=some_value
```

You should use:

```
"UPDATE yesData
SET addressEmail=newemail
WHERE socialSecNum="."%$searchTerm%";
```